# Microsoft Graph API - user extension data in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have an Azure AD B2C directory with some users in it. I have been using the Microsoft Graph API and through both https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and PostMan I have been able to create and modify users along with including an extension attribute (eg: `extension_[guid in our tenant]_ContactMethod`) - details passed in json in the body of the request in PostMan.

That is fine, however I need to be albe to do the same in C#. I can successfully create the user without specifying any extensions:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var user = new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = "John Smith",
    MailNickname = "JohnSimth",
    UserPrincipalName = "JohnSmith@[tenant].onmicrosoft.com",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
        Password = "[Randomly Generated Password]"
    }
    //[Extension attributes to add here]
};

await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user);
```

However I need to be able to specify some extension attributes when creating / modifying the user in C#. How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot directly add extensions at the time of creation according to this [limitations document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#creating-a-resource-and-open-extension-at-the-same-time).

After creating the user, you need to create a separate request that hits the extensions endpoint as shown in the below code and this adds these extension details to the user.

```
var extension = new OpenTypeExtension
{
    ExtensionName = "{ExtensionName}",
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"FirstEmail", "abc@yahoo.com"},
                    {"SecondEmail" , "xyz@yahoo.com"}
                }
};

await graphClient.Users["{UserId}"].Extensions
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(extension);
```

So just after user creation, get that userid and use it to hit extensions endpoint as shown in the above code.

Comment: This doesn't work. For a start I can't assign a value to the extension. And then when I do run the above code, it does not add an extension to the user.

Comment: @penguin178 Apologies for not giving the exact code as I have explained my answer in general way how you need to add extensions to your user :)-